# Modifying a URL to strip out the pathname and set it to the address bar

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a website that when going to the homepage it shows the file directory and the aspx page for example: http://www.something.com/Common/WebPage/default.aspx 
What I am trying to find is hopefully find an easy way perferably in Javascript to rewrite the address in the browser to http://www.something.com when going to the homepage. Basically I am trying to do what cnn.com has done already and other sites

Comment: do you mean a redirect where the user is sent to a different address, or do you want to rewrite the string in the browser URL to something different?

Comment: @acutesoftware I want to rewrite the string in the browser URL to something different? Like cnn.com when you go to the homepage it stays on http://www.cnn.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to register routing in the global.asax file as per below:

```
Sub Application_Start(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    RegisterRoutes(Routing.RouteTable.Routes)
End Sub

Public Shared Sub RegisterRoutes(ByVal routeCollection As Routing.RouteCollection)
    routeCollection.MapPageRoute("DefPage", "", "~/common/webpage/default.aspx")
End Sub
```

Comment: so this will be available to remove the ~/common/webpage/default.aspx" from the address bar? if so how does it work bec I tried im unable to even see a change

Comment: It won't remove the url from the bar if you go to that url directly. However, if you open `http://www.something.com`, it will display your default.aspx page directly and the url will stay the same.

Comment: And if you don't want users going directly to `http://www.something.com/Common/WebPage/default.aspx`, then in the page load event you can check if the url is the full one and redirect as follows `If Request.Url.AbsolutePath.Contains("default.aspx") Then Response.Redirect("http://www.something.com")`

Comment: ok i put that in the global.asax of the application, am i suppose to do anything else bec when i got www.something.com it dosent behave any differently i just changed the global.asax nothing more

Comment: i made a demo when typing in "customer/4" in url it will go to the customer.aspx page with 4, routeCollection.MapPageRoute("RouteForCustomer", "Customer/{Id}", "~/Customer.aspx"). From the answer it seems that the 3rd param is the targeted aspx page and the second param is pattern to look up? not sure if this makes sense routeCollection.MapPageRoute("DefPage", "", "~/common/webpage/default.aspx")

Comment: Yes, it does. Here is a registration we have used in one of our production sites for many years: `routeCollection.MapPageRoute("HOME", String.Empty, "~/home.aspx")`. It works beautifully - users never see home.aspx in the url, just the site name.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really something you can do in a script.

But you can use [`URLRewrite`](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) for this long as you're using IIS.